# Console warning "[nuxt] Cannot load payload... _payload.js" warning on dynamic routes in static site

Tags: nuxtjs3

I am upgrading my static site from Nuxt3-RC3 to Nuxt3-RC11.

After upgrading I get a lot of errors and warnings in the console related to my dynamic routes (/m/[...slug].vue). It appears, that Nuxt is trying to prefect the dynamic pages it finds links to (e.g. /m/some/page) by looking up an _payload.js for each dynamic route. The warning is, that

```
ERROR: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

WARNING: entry.8994fad8.js:5 [nuxt] Cannot load payload  /m/d6746dd9-497b-4f9a-8201-513b19762ccd/f6358aa0-07a4-46c4-b3eb-9d6c515f07c7/_payload.js TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: /m/d6746dd9-497b-4f9a-8201-513b19762ccd/f6358aa0-07a4-46c4-b3eb-9d6c515f07c7/_payload.js
(anonymous) @ entry.8994fad8.js:5
```

When I click to open the _payload.js in the browser file I can see, that it is rendered as an html file which explains the mime type error.

But, why is Nuxt throwing these errors and warnings and how can I avoid them?

Comment: You could maybe try to delete the `.nuxt` directory (cache) and see if it helps. Otherwise, maybe also nuke your lock file.

Comment: Thanks @kissu. I have tried deleting the .nuxt folder, node_modules, lock-file and doing a fresh install already

Comment: seems to be a ongoing problem with nuxt3 and ssg.  and no obvious solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer a problem. Solution is to upgrade to the new stable Nuxt3